# Downloading CSV on AIX - Alternatives to wget?

Tags: csv, unix, curl, wget, aix

I require to download a csv file via an HTML link (e.g. www.abc.com/test.csv) but I am unable to do so on my AIX flavored UNIX server using wget.

Unfortunately wget is not loaded for my server and thus using the above always fails with "Could not load program wget".

Is there any alternative that I could try out? I know I could simply attempt to install wget on the server but as a user it is not managed by me and I will not have the permissions to do so.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does the Web site require SS/TLS/HTTPS?

Comment: It requires HTTPS - yes

Comment: Well, you can't use telnet, then.

Comment: If you have the GNU toolchain on AIX, then I would try installing it to my local user directory `./configure --prefix ~/local`

Comment: `curl` maybe???

Comment: I'm looking at curl right now - right now what I've played with is still inconclusive but it works so far for general sites like google.com

The issue is I am on a private network so a bit more difficult accessing internal domains. I'm attempting to get a public DNS and see if I can feed curl with that.

Comment: @SaiyamSethi - I think your concern is the self-signed certificate. You can coerce `curl` to accept the connection even without verification of the certificate. Use `-k` option.

Comment: @OP: I guess someone (most likely yourself) has played with `LIBPATH` that's why `wget` doesn't start. Please quote the _complete_ output of this command: `(unset LIBPATH; wget)` Edit: also read this: http://web.axelero.hu/lzsiga/aix-linking.html#Q0022

Comment: @alvits thanks i'm going to try out the -k option and see if it works out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `openssl`, then you could connect using it

```
$ ( echo "GET /test.csv HTTP/1.1";
    echo "Host: www.abc.com";
    echo "User-Agent: $(openssl version) / $(bash --version | head -n 1) ";
    echo "Connection: close";
    echo; echo;
    sleep 1 ) | openssl s_client -connect 172.16.254.1:443
```

And then if you want to try extracting the file a little with sed, you could:

```
( echo "GET /test.csv HTTP/1.1";
  echo "Host: www.abc.com";
  echo "User-Agent: $(openssl version) / $(bash --version | head -n 1) ";
  echo "Connection: close";
  echo; echo;
  sleep 1 ) | openssl s_client -connect 172.16.254.1:443 \
            | sed -ne '/^HTTP\/1.1/,$p' \
            | sed -ne '/^\r$/,$p' \
            | sed 1,2d > test.csv
```

If the `\r` doesn't work, then you'll need to enter a carriage return manually in the shell.  This is typically `^V^M` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>)

I didn't test this on an AIX server, so use at your own risk.

If the User-Agent line gives you trouble, then just delete it.

Comment: I do have ssl so this might work. Unfortunately, the next issue is that I am on a private network - and so is the domain I am trying to access so looks like ssl will require an IP. 

I'll see if I can gather and let you know if this works :)

Thanks!

Comment: So then use the IP in the `-connect`

Answer (score 0):

This one is difficult to answer but there were a couple things that I discovered on this issue.

When it comes to using wget I was unable to do so due the the package not being available. Though I was able to contact my UNIX admin and have it installed for use which pretty much solved the problem.

However, I understand that this will not be an appropriate solution for everyone. After playing around with curl and openssl I found that you can achieve the same as wget but with a bit more work required.

Only issue I reside on top of is I am unable to connect to the actual host - keep getting connection refused but that's likely due to firewall issues on my end.